# How to get jsonschema to use a boolean of false OR attributes

Tags: jsonschema

I'm creating an `Avatar` in json schema, and in my app, if we want to hide the avatar, we pass it in as `false`, otherwise, an avatar has an image and a name.

In json schema, I specify avatar as

```
const avatarSchema = {
    "type": ["object", "boolean"],
    "required": [],
    "additionalProperties": false,    
    "properties":{
       "name": {
           "type": "string"
        },
       "image": {
           "type": "string",
           "format": "url"
        }
    }
};
```

This doesn't work because if `Avatar = true`, `'image' does not exist on type 'Avatar'.
  Property 'image' does not exist on type 'true'.`

I don't want `Avatar` to every be `true`, it's either `false` or `{image, name}`, how can I tell json schema to operate this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your explanation of why your schema doesn't work is not correct. The `required`, `additionalProperties`, and `properties` keywords only apply if the data being validated is an object. So, the schema should work as you want except that it can have value "true".

If the validator you are using is giving an error message like the one in your question, it is not validating correctly. You should file a bug report for that validator.

Anyway, the solution to your problem requires the `anyOf` keyword.

```
{
  "anyOf": [
    { "enum": [false] },
    {
      "type": "object",
      "required": ["name", "image"],
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "name": { "type": "string" },
        "image": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "url"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```